# Reload page and change class of an element

Tags: jquery

I want to reload the window and after this make the `cart_mobile` active. 
How can this be done? I tried this:

```
$('.open_cart').on('click', function () {
  location.reload();
  $('.cart_mobile').delay(2000).addClass('cart_mobile_active');
});
```

Comment: That's not how HTML/HTTP works. You cannot affect the page *after* you call reload. This can be done by setting a flag in the querystring/localstorage/session and reading it when the page next loads and amending the HTML as needed. However, given all you're doing is adding a class to the element, I don't see the point of reloading at all

Comment: You should assume that anything after a reload will not run. You'll need to set some sort of flag that you can listen for when the page loads, then run your "after-reload" code.

Comment: Agreed with @RoryMcCrossan  as well as DBS too, i think you didn't need `location.reload();` at all. please remove it and try once.

Comment: Are you using php or another code as well after reloading the page ? if yes, then you have to update it through a flag etc... because you are using jquery to control frontend, but for permanent action you need backend code to achieve it. I think you mean this ?

Answer (score 0):

please try it :

```
$('.open_cart').on('click', function () {
   location.reload();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.cart_mobile').delay(2000).addClass('cart_mobile_active');
});
```